# How to make a variable text in a text field by using a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make such a box (textarea or inputtextfield) with a variable text in there and the variable depends on javascipt variable.

For example:

```
var a=prompt('some text');
if (a==1) {
   link="www.google.com"
} else if (a==2) {
    link="www.facebook.com"
}
```

and I have a `textarea` or input text field and their value in the text box can change to be either `"www.google.com"` or `"www.facebook.com"`

Comment: <input type="text" id="tx" >
I don't know how to set its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the following:

HTML

```
  <input type="text" id="textfield" />
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

USING JS ONLY

```
 var a=prompt('some text');
 var link = '';
 if (a==1) {link="www.google.com";}
 else if (a==2) {link="www.facebook.com";}
 document.getElementById('textfield').value = link;
 document.getElementById('textarea').innerText = link;
```

***OR*** BY USING jQuery

```
 var a=prompt('some text');
 var link = '';
 if (a==1) {link="www.google.com";}
 else if (a==2) {link="www.facebook.com";}
 $('#textfield').val(link);
 $('#textarea').text(link);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been searching for this since yesterday til I think that this website can help me so I asked here. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider that this is your input field

```
<input type="text" name="link" />
```

To set the value to the input field, use the following jQuery code:

```
var a = prompt("Enter a value :");
var str = "";
var field = $('input[name=link]');
if(a===1)
  str = "www.google.com");
if(a===2)
  str = "www.facebook.com");
$(field).html(str);
```